# Jenkins Pipeline Wipe Out Workspace

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, workspace

We are running Jenkins 2.x and love the new Pipeline plugin.  However, with so many branches in a repository, disk space fills up quickly.

Is there any plugin that's compatible with Pipeline that I can wipe out the workspace on a successful build?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

You can use [`deleteDir()`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#deletedir-recursively-delete-the-current-directory-from-the-workspace) as the last step of the pipeline Jenkinsfile (assuming you didn't change the working directory).

Comment: I have problems with deleteDir(). It seems to randomly not able to delete the current directory when the node gets build on a slave. The build fails of course if this happens. So be aware if your jobs fail randomly. I don't understand why node not just cleans it workspace when the node starts building. Because the node can run anywhere you can't make any assumptions about the files in the workspace anyway.

Comment: But I think will only delete the workspace on the current node. In the general case your pipeline will runs on several different slaves.

Comment: I put this at the beggining right before `checkout scm`.

Comment: I put this at the beginning also, in case the project fails before it reaches the end, or the next build is on a different slave.

Comment: This is the command documented to clean up the workspace in the ["Cleaning up and notifications"](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/post/) section of the Jenkins documentation.

Comment: Beware `deleteDir()` won't work in a docker container. [JENKINS-41894](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-41894)

Answer (score 161):

Like @gotgenes pointed out with **Jenkins Version. 2.74**, the below works, not sure since when, maybe if some one can edit and add the version above

```
cleanWs()
```

---

With, **Jenkins Version 2.16** and the [Workspace Cleanup Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Workspace+Cleanup+Plugin), that I have, I use

```
step([$class: 'WsCleanup'])
```

to delete the workspace.

You can view it by going to

```
JENKINS_URL/job/<any Pipeline project>/pipeline-syntax
```

Then selecting "step: General Build Step" from Sample step and then selecting "Delete workspace when build is done" from Build step

Comment: This works for me: Jenkins 2.7.2, Workspace Cleanup Plugin 0.30

Comment: According to [this PR](https://github.com/jenkinsci/ws-cleanup-plugin/pull/30/files#diff-4b88580f361d14ff592e5f06a99026ccR258), included in [0.33](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Workspace+Cleanup+Plugin#WorkspaceCleanupPlugin-Release0.33(2017-04-24)), this is called in the pipeline as `cleanWs`.

Answer (score 143):

The mentioned solutions `deleteDir()` and `cleanWs()` (if using the [workspace cleanup plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Workspace+Cleanup+Plugin)) both work, **but the recommendation to use it in an extra build step is usually not the desired solution**.  If the build fails and the pipeline is aborted, this cleanup-stage is never reached and therefore the workspace is not cleaned on failed builds.

=> In most cases you should probably put it in a [post-built-step condition](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post-conditions) like `always`:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            steps {
                echo 'Hello World'
            }
        }
    }
    post { 
        always { 
            cleanWs()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This was absolutely key for my use case.  I need to archive artifacts from the job, and running `cleanWs()` as a step deletes them before the post build archive command runs.  `cleanWs()` should most likely always be run as a post build command

Comment: If you have only one `post` section, `cleanWs()` can safely be put into the `always` condition, but the safest spot is inside the `cleanup` condition: `post { cleanup { cleanWs() } }`

Answer (score 72):

In fact the deleteDir function recursively deletes the current directory and its contents. Symbolic links and junctions will not be followed but will be removed.

To delete a specific directory of a workspace wrap the deleteDir step in a dir step.

```
dir('directoryToDelete') {
    deleteDir()
}
```

Comment: Although the OP asked merely how to delete the workspace, this answer is the most informative.

Answer (score 34):

Using the following pipeline script:

```
pipeline {
    agent { label "master" }
    options { skipDefaultCheckout() }
    stages {
        stage('CleanWorkspace') {
            steps {
                cleanWs()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Follow these steps:

1. Navigate to the latest build of the pipeline job you would like to clean the workspace of.
2. Click the Replay link in the LHS menu.
3. Paste the above script in the text box and click Run

Comment: Add `options { skipDefaultCheckout() }` for a little faster execution.

Comment: Improved answer with your suggestion @AkisK

Comment: Seems like this is the only option that works for cleaning up the workspace BEFORE and NOT AFTER executing a pipeline, even though I didn't want to have a separate step for just clean up. Thank you

Answer (score 29):

I used deleteDir() as follows:

```
  post {
        always {
            deleteDir() /* clean up our workspace */
        }
    }
```

However, I then had to also run a Success or Failure AFTER always but you cannot order the post conditions. 
The  current order is always, changed, aborted, failure, success and then unstable.

However, there is a very useful post condition, **cleanup** which always runs last, see https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/

So in the end my post was as follows :

```
post {
    always {

    }
    success{

    }
    failure {

    }
    cleanup{
        deleteDir()
    }
}
```

Hopefully this may be helpful for some corner cases

Comment: We get an error "invalid condition cleanup", we are using Jenkins version 2.89

Comment: In my opnion, this is one of the best answer, however, I would recommand to not delete the data in the failing case such as you are keeping debug data. Moreover, deleting the data at the beginning is also a good solution.

Answer (score 18):

If you have used custom workspace in Jenkins then deleteDir() will not delete @tmp folder.

So to delete @tmp along with workspace use following

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        node {
            customWorkspace "/home/jenkins/jenkins_workspace/${JOB_NAME}_${BUILD_NUMBER}"
        }
    }
    post {
        cleanup {
            /* clean up our workspace */
            deleteDir()
            /* clean up tmp directory */
            dir("${workspace}@tmp") {
                deleteDir()
            }
            /* clean up script directory */
            dir("${workspace}@script") {
                deleteDir()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**This snippet will work for default workspace also.**

Comment: Also works with a dockerized pipeline.  Very helpful, thanks!

Comment: This is also the only answer I've seen that can kill the annoying @libs folder too

Comment: what is the difference between cleanWs and deleteDir?

Comment: @White https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54019121/what-is-the-difference-between-deletedir-cleanws-and-wscleanup-in-jenkins-pi

Answer (score 9):

Using the 'WipeWorkspace' extension seems to work as well.  It requires the longer form:

```
checkout([
   $class: 'GitSCM',
   branches: scm.branches,
   extensions: scm.extensions + [[$class: 'WipeWorkspace']],
   userRemoteConfigs: scm.userRemoteConfigs
])
```

More details here: https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/226122247-How-to-Customize-Checkout-for-Pipeline-Multibranch-

Available GitSCM extensions here: https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/tree/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/git/extensions/impl

Answer (score 9):

For Jenkins 2.190.1 this works for sure:

```
    post {
        always {
            cleanWs deleteDirs: true, notFailBuild: true
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    tools {nodejs "node"}
    
    environment {

    }

    parameters {
        string(name: 'FOLDER', defaultValue: 'ABC', description: 'FOLDER', trim: true)

    }

    stages {
        stage('1') {
            steps{
            }
        }
        stage("2") {
            steps {
            }     
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            echo "Release finished do cleanup and send mails"
            deleteDir()
        }
        success {
            echo "Release Success"
        }
        failure {
            echo "Release Failed"
        }
        cleanup {
            echo "Clean up in post work space"
            cleanWs()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the difference between cleanWs and deleteDir? upvoted you

Answer (score 4):

We make sure we are working with a clean workspace by using a feature of the git plugin. You can add additional behaviors like 'Clean before checkout'. We use this as well for 'Prune stale remote-tracking branches'.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I want to clear out old files at the *beginning* of the build, but this is problematic since the source code has been checked out.

My solution is to ask git to clean out any files (from the last build) that it doesn't know about:

```
    sh "git clean -x -f"
```

That way I can start the build out clean, and if it fails, the workspace isn't cleaned out and therefore easily debuggable.

Answer (score 2):

[Cleaning up](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/post/) : Since the post section of a Pipeline is guaranteed to run at the end of a Pipeline’s execution, we can add some notification or other steps to perform finalization, notification, or other end-of-Pipeline tasks.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('No-op') {
            steps {
                sh 'ls'
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        cleanup {
            echo 'One way or another, I have finished'
            deleteDir() /* clean up our workspace */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work when having stages running on different slaves!

Answer (score 1):

Currently both deletedir() and cleanWs() do not work properly when using Jenkins kubernetes plugin, the pod workspace is deleted but the master workspace persists

it should not be a problem for persistant branches, when you have a step to clean the workspace prior to checkout scam. It will basically reuse the same workspace over and over again: but when using multibranch pipelines the master keeps the whole workspace and git directory

I believe this should be an issue with Jenkins, 
any enlightenment here?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this:

```
post {
        success {
            cleanWs()
        }
    }
```