# How to cleanup pipeline before checkout of repository in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-declarative-pipeline, jenkins-git-plugin

I want to make a `clean before checkout` operation which is described in Jenkins git plugin [documentation](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git/#extensions):

> Clean before checkout Clean the workspace before every checkout by
>   deleting all untracked files and directories, including those which
>   are specified in .gitignore. ...

But how can add this option to default checkout step which is doing as first step?

I feel that it should be an option extended by git plugin which can be included to `options` block of Jenkinsfile as described in [docs](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#options):

> The options directive allows configuring Pipeline-specific options
>   from within the Pipeline itself. Pipeline provides a number of these
>   options, such as buildDiscarder, but they may also be provided by
>   **plugins**...

But how one should know which options and their names this plugin offer? Didn't find it in docs, also i may be wrong that `clean before checkout` should be placed in `options` block of Jenkinsfile.

Please help.

Comment: You could `skipDefaultCheckout(true)` and then do an explicit `checkout` to specify options.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments the way to go is to use `skipDefaultCheckout()` ([Source](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#available-options)) in your pipeline-options to not checkout the repository if the pipeline starts.

> **skipDefaultCheckout**
>
> Skip checking out code from source control by
>   default in the agent directive.

To get the repository manually you can use `checkout scm` ([Source](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/))

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    options {
        skipDefaultCheckout()
    }
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            steps {
                // Cleanup before starting the stage
                // deleteDir() / cleanWs() or your own way of cleaning up

                // Checkout the repository
                checkout scm 

                // do whatever you like
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Michael and zett42! Works! But it's also need specify git url repo in checkout command to make a clean checkout. It can checkout without repo url, but making clean only when repo url is specified. I am looking into var GIT_URL which git plugin has but see error: "No such property: GIT_URL".

Is there any other way retrieve git url which specified in Jenkins GUI at job config page?

Comment: @pleyades Not following. You say it works ... but then imply it doesn't. What works? And what doesn't work? What makes you think you need the URL? I use 'checkout scm' and it uses the URL (and all the other settings) configured in the Pipeline section of the pipeline job config.

Comment: @steve maybe not clear comment, yes. It works in that way as suggested - skip default checkout and add your user defined checkout. However what is not worked - is GIT_URL variable, which i assumed, should be available for your custom checkout step. I have defined GIT_URL in environment section. However if default checkout step is not skipped - GIT_URL is visible, even if not specified in environment section. Any questions?

Comment: According to this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/54020444/104085) we shouldn't use deleteDir command in docker image and cleaWs command before building process has not been done.

Comment: If you use ``skipDefaultCheckout()``, all of environment variable of git plugins don't completed.

Comment: It works but if you checkout on different agents you might have different results due to different timing.

Answer (score 1):

One of my jobs I used this:

```
    def gitCheckoutExtensions = []
    if (cleanWorkspace) {
        println '>>> workspace will be cleaned and retrieved all codes again..!'
        gitCheckoutExtensions.push([$class: 'CleanBeforeCheckout'])
    }

    gitCheckoutExtensions.push([$class: 'LocalBranch', localBranch: srcBranch])

    checkout([
        $class: 'GitSCM',
        branches: [[name: "*/${srcBranch}"]],
        doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
        extensions: gitCheckoutExtensions,
        submoduleCfg: [],
        userRemoteConfigs: [
            [
                credentialsId: credId,
                url: url
            ]
        ]
    ])
```

Longer form of stage is:

```
@Library('gui_multi_repo@master')_


pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            label "DockerAgent"
            image "node:14.21.3"
        }
    }
    
    parameters {
        string(trim: true, name: 'REPO_URL', defaultValue: "http://user.name@server_domain_or_ipAddres", description: 'Repo adresi')
        string(trim: true, name: 'REPO_CRED_ID', defaultValue: RepoCredId, description: 'GIT Repo bağlantısı olacaksa CRED_ID kullanılacak')
        string(trim: true, name: 'REPO_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME', defaultValue: 'refs/remotes/origin/developer', description: 'Kodları hangi BRANCH üstünden çekeceğini belirtiyoruz')
        string(trim: true, name: 'REPO_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME', defaultValue: 'refs/remotes/origin/master', description: 'Push ile kodun gönderileceği branch')
    }
    
    stages {
        stage("Git İşlemleri") {
            steps {
                script {
                    def credId="${params.REPO_CRED_ID}"
                    def repoUrl="${params.REPO_URL}"
                    def srcBranch="${params.REPO_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME}"
                    def targetBranch="${params.REPO_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME}"
                    def tagName="cem13"
                    def tagMessage="naber13"
                    
                    echo "credId: $credId"
                    echo "repoUrl: $repoUrl"
                    echo "srcBranch: $srcBranch"
                    echo "targetBranch: $targetBranch"
                    echo "tagName: $tagName"
                    echo "tagMessage: $tagMessage"
                    
                    /** 
                     * CredId ile tanımlanan Git kimlik bilgilerini alır
                     * Artık GIT_USERNAME ve GIT_PASSWORD değişkenleri içinde, verilen credId'nin
                     * kullanıcı adı ve şifresi olacak ve tüm çıktılarda *** ile gizlenecek
                     */
                    
                    checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',
                        branches: [[name: "${srcBranch}"]],
                        extensions: [
                            [$class: 'CleanBeforeCheckout']
                        ],
                        userRemoteConfigs: [[
                            // credId veya gitCredentials.id ile tanımlanan kullanıcı bilgilerinin id değeri verilir
                            credentialsId: "${credId}", 
                            url: "${repoUrl}"
                        ]]
                    ])
                    
                    withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: "${credId}", passwordVariable: 'GIT_PASSWORD', usernameVariable: 'GIT_USERNAME')]) {
                        
                        def gitUrlWithCredentials = repoUrl.replaceFirst(/(http[s]:\/\/).*@(.*)/,"\$1${GIT_USERNAME}:${GIT_PASSWORD}@\$2")
                        echo "gitUrlWithCredentials: ${gitUrlWithCredentials}"
                        
                        sh """
                            #!/bin/sh -e
                            
                            git config --global credential.helper cache
                            git config --global push.default simple
                            
                            # Kullanıcı e-posta adresini ayarlar
                            git config --global user.email "${GIT_USERNAME}@domain.com"
                            
                            # Kullanıcı adını ayarlar
                            git config --global user.name "${GIT_USERNAME.replace('.', ' '}" 
                            
                            # SSL Doğrulama yapmaz
                            git config --global http.sslverify 'false'
                            
                            # Git URL'sinde parolayı kullanarak güncellenmiş URL'yi oluşturun
                            git tag -a ${tagName} -m '${tagMessage}'
                         
                            git push ${gitUrlWithCredentials} ${tagName}
                            
                            git checkout ${targetBranch}
                            
                            # sonra birleştireceğimiz 'kaynak dalını' isteyelim
                            git merge ${srcBranch}
                            
                            git push ${gitUrlWithCredentials} ${targetBranch}
                        """
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    post { 
        success{
            echo "** Süreç başarıyla tamamlandı"
        }
        failure {
            echo "** Süreç hatalı tamamlandı"
        }
        cleanup{
            echo "** Süreç tamamlandı cleanup zamanı"
        }
        always { 
            echo "** Süreç günahıyla sevabıyla tamamlandı"
        }
    }

}
```