# Jenkins Delete Dir after Job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have a number of Jenkins pipeline and I would like to delete the directory when the pipeline finishes, (pass or fail).

I have added the following stage to all of my pipelines.

```
    post {
        always {
                step([$class: 'WsCleanup'])
        }
    }
```

This does work, but somewhere during the clean up it creates another folder in the same dir and makes it as *ws-cleanup* eg.
`myservices_ws-cleanup_1571049838662`

Is it possible to delete the directory without creating the ws-cleanup directory?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28683914/is-there-any-way-to-cleanup-jenkins-workspace

Comment: Hi @Adiii, I think these approaches still leave the ws-cleanup directory after it is finished cleaning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `post` looks more Jenkins `declarative pipeline` combined with `scripted Jenkins pipeline`

```
post {
    always {
       script {    
            step([$class: 'WsCleanup'])
       }
    }
}
```

if you want to combine this don't forget to use `script` block.
And btw, when you start a job and if the job runs on Jenkins Slave then Jenkins will create a `workdir` with the job name specified in the `Jenkins UI`.

My understanding is if you will do a `post` condition on your pipelines with `cleanWs()` that will clean up the `content` inside the `workspace` folder, but not the entire folder... the folder-name will remain(empty).

That makes possible to start/test a fresh new/next Job on a fresh `workspace`.

Here is the answer to your question [Check the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37468455/8780756)

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I ended up going with the `deleteDir()`

Answer (score 0):

Is not cleanWs() working for your purpose? If not you can always use the deleteDir() option

```
post {
    always {
            cleanWs()
    }
}
```